# How to show user timetable's items width do not necessarily match with time

Tags: calendar, timeline, information-design

I am currently designing a timetable for a web app which will show appointments as they are scheduled.

Problem is, as I think that in order to make the user understand the scheduled appointment beforehand there is some important information that has to be displayed (Title, time, customer), appointments that are too short in duration will have to have a different width than the time they represent.

My question is, how do I make the user understand that the appointment's width does not **necessarily** match the time?

I came up with this idea, but I think this still is not straightforward enough...

[image]

Update:
This is how the timeline is looking following Ashwin's advice.

[image]

I'm open to any kind of suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question! I'm not sure if I have a solution but displaying the customer image, name and other details at all times could very easily lead to a busy screen. And for someone who has a lot of appointments, it could even turn the page unusable. Also, what if there are overlapping appointments?

I love how Google Calendar sort of handles this by only displaying the event name -which is what a user is mostly concerned with.

[image]

This would help reduce the size of your container by a huge amount. You could display the rest of the details on hover like so:

[image]

This would also make overlapping appointments fairly easy to browse through:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Displaying details on hover is a really good idea. Although overlapping appointments are not initially going to be a thing, having a busy screen could be a problem, so thanks for you advice!